# sub divs css formatting problem?

Tags: html, css

i have this simple layout css which provide 3 rows layout
css code

```
<style type="text/css">  
body {
width:750px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:30px;
}



/* ----- HEADER ----- */



#header {
width:750px;
height:150px;
background-color:#333333;
}



/* ----- MAIN CONTENT ----- */



#content { 
width:750px;
background-color:#333333;
margin-top:10px;
min-height:500px; /* for modern browsers */
height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
}



/* ----- FOOTER ----- */



#footer { 
width:750px;
height:100px;
background-color:#333333;
margin-top:10px;
}
</style>
```

and here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>example page</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="header"> 
    </div> 
<div id="content"> 
    </div> 
<div id="footer"> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

what i need to do that every div created with in the header div must have float to left format

```
<div id="header"><div>welcome</div></div>
```

this for example this div have welcome must have float left format without passing any class or id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can do:

```
#header div { float: left; }
```

But why? Can you not use span instead of div? If you don't need id or class tags, why any tags at all?

Comment: because i implement php script which will create divs and i can't create spans coz those divs will have another issue with another template

Comment: ok... well... above will work for you then. It would be better practice to use the class attribute instead of tagNames. Please, do consider it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a "clearing" your div. When you float an element it's container wouldn't extend to fit the child element anymore. Read this great [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) about clearing. 
I fixed your code with just adding an clearing div after welcome div in header.

```
<div id="header"> 
    <div> Welcome dude!</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS for clearing div

```
.clear{clear:both; height:0;}
```

Look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJptb/1/) too